# App crashes when removing child view controller from its parent

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I'm trying to test some animations between `UIViewControllers` and in this particular case I have a `UIViewController` that adds another `UIVC` as its child view.

Everything works as expected, the child view gets added and presented, then on the child view I have a `UINavigationBar` which has a cancel button (dismiss) as its left bar button.

When I click on that button, I fire a function which tries to remove this presented child view, from the view hierarchy (from its parent view).

Code from the parent view:

```
    // ViewController -> Parent

lazy var presentButton: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton(type: .custom)
    b.setTitle("Present", for: .normal)
    b.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapPresentButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return b
}()

lazy var childViewController: PresentedViewController = {
    let viewController = PresentedViewController()
    return viewController
}()


@objc func didTapPresentButton() {
    addViewControllerAsChildViewController(childViewController: childViewController)    
}


func addViewControllerAsChildViewController(childViewController: UIViewController) {
    self.addChildViewController(childViewController)
    childViewController.view.frame = CGRect.zero

    self.view.addSubview(childViewController.view)

    let newFrame = view.bounds
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        childViewController.view.frame = newFrame
    }
    childViewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

As you see above, when I click the present button, it instantiates the child view and animates it in, so far so good.

Child View code:

```
// ChildViewController -> Child (ofc)

@objc func didTapCancel() {
    self.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

Now on the child view, when I click the cancel button, I know I have to call the `removeFromParentViewController()` in order to it be properly removed, but the app crashes if I do that with the followingg error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[dismissLayerTest.ChildViewController name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fea2f60a920'
```

Then I tried to comment the `self.removeFromParentViewController()` line, and by doing so, the app doesn't crash, but then on the parent view controller I can see that the view is still attached to its parent by printing `self.childViewControllers.count` and it shows me `1`.

Can you see where the problem is ?

Thanks

Comment: Search 'name' in your code to find where the error is.

Comment: @YunCHEN there's not any ´name´ property or method call with that :/

Comment: It didn’t help. This crash doesn’t appear on the link you’ve mentioned neither the view hierarchy is the same in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out where the problem was.

After some tests, I discovered that we should not use `lazy` instantiations while using `parent-child View Controllers`.

Since the I instantiated the `childViewController` as `lazy` when I tried to remove it from the `parentViewController` the error said `unrecognized selector sent to instance` so I found out that the property pointer-selector was somehow deallocated on the `parentViewController` which didn't knew what child it was to dismiss, because it lost its reference.

In order to fix it, I removed the `lazy` instantiation, so it remains always in scope and now I can successfully remove the child from its parent scope.

```
var childViewController: ChildViewController = {
    let viewController = ChildViewController()
    return viewController
}()
```

Comment: Thank you! Interesting moment!